# Call Btn is giving wrong number

Tags: ios, swift

I set an `IBAction` fucntion in Swift 3 Xcode 10.1 and this code bellow, using back end db as back4app where i store data and numbers
but after hitting call button that should retrieve numbers from columns it give me word like this `Optional(6788899)`
instead of the number only to be able to make the call via the mobile phone, what can cause this word to appear any help please

```
//check for missing data
if(phone == nil || phone == 0){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "No phone available", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}else{
    let url:URL = URL(string: "tel://" + String(describing:phone))!
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary([:]), completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: `String(describing:)` should only be used for printing debug messages. If you find it being used in any other case then you are probably doing it incorrectly.

Comment: The code does exactly what it's supposed to do. You tell Swift to *describe* an optional as a string, and that's what it does. Your mistake is that you actually don't want to *describe* anything! You want to convert to string. Please do not use `String(describing:)` in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unwrap the optional `phone`.

```
let url = URL(string: "tel://" + String(describing:phone!))!
```

---

However this is a *swiftier* way to do that.

And please don't misuse `String(describing:`

```
//check for missing data
if let phoneNumber = phone, phoneNumber != 0 {
    let url = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)")!
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary([:]), completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "No phone available", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```